# Error while creating XNA project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, xna

[image]I installed XNA for VS 2012 ultimate from [XNA Codeplex](https://msxna.codeplex.com/releases). But, when I try to create Windows Game (4.0) 
 I am getting  declaration error.

The error is

```
A problem was encountered creating the sub project 'WindowsGame1'.The imported project
" C:\Program Files (x86)\.....\XNA Game Studio\Microsoft.Xna.GameStudio.targets" was not found
```

I am using Windows 8.1 64 Bit and VS 2012 ultimate

Thanks

Comment: Did you follow the "Before install extension:" steps? And IMO you would be better off with MonoGame (The open source implementation of XNA). It's almost the same thing, but fully supported.

Comment: +@Pierre-LucPineault And MonoGame sounds cooler

Comment: Doesn't Monogame need for XNA to be installed in the PC in order to execute properly?